# Optimal algorithm- choosing subset of sets which minimises the cost

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dynamic

I have list of products, and need to write an algorithm that will calculate a minimal price to the customer.

Each product has its own price, and there is a group price - the price of several products together.

The algorithm will calculate which groups to choose to get a minimum price

> **For example:**
>
> Suppose the customer wants to purchase the products c1,c2,c3,c4

> the prices are: **c1**=70$, **c2**=70$,
> **c3**=70$, **c4**=70$.
>
> **When the groups are:**
>
> **g1** = {c1, c2} = 120 $
> **g2** = {c3, c4} = 130
> **g3** = {c2, c3, c4} = 170
>
> The options are:
>
> **1.** pay for each product separately $ 70,=  **280$**
>
> **2.** select to buy group g1,g2=  **250$**
>
> **3.** select to buy group g3 + product c1 separately =  **240$**
>
> may be there are more options, anyway - in this example the most
> affordable price is the third option, group g3+c1, 240$.

**What algorithm can solve the problem?**

Go through all the possible groups combinations, and find out what the minimum price is and which groups to use.

I'm sure it's a familiar algorithm, A question that exists in [geeks for geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org), I just do not know how to set it, what its famous name.

Comment: What a strangely specific question: it's almost as if it's a CS assignment :P

Comment: More context please? And a better explanation would be super nice

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879667/optimization-choosing-subset-of-sets-which-minimises-the-cost

Comment: yes, the question is the same idea, but I didn't understand the solution there, what combos and what cost the algorithm return for the example.

Comment: @PessiS. if you want to go through all combinations, you can use backtracking. Might post a code example of that later if needed.

Comment: It's called "Weighted Set Cover"

Answer (score 0):

Set Cover Problem - GeeksforGeeks:

```
public static int minCostCollection(final Set<Integer> unv, final Set<Integer>[] sets,
        final Map<Set, Integer> costs, final List<Set> list, final int pos) {

    if (unv.size() == 0) {
        int cost = 0;
        for (final Set s : list) {
            cost = cost + costs.get(s);
        }
        return cost;
    }
    if (pos < 0) {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    final Set<Integer> unvCopy = new HashSet<>(unv);
    final List<Set> list1 = new ArrayList<>(list);
    list.add(sets[pos]);
    for (final Integer elem : sets[pos]) {
        unv.remove(elem);
    }
    final int cost1 = minCostCollection(unv, sets, costs, list, pos - 1);
    final int cost2 = minCostCollection(unvCopy, sets, costs, list1, pos - 1);
    return Math.min(cost1, cost2);

}


public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Set<Integer> unv = new HashSet<>();
        unv.add(1);
        unv.add(2);
        unv.add(3);
        unv.add(4);
        unv.add(5);
        final Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<>();
        s1.add(4);
        s1.add(1);
        s1.add(3);
        final Set<Integer> s2 = new HashSet<>();
        s2.add(2);
        s2.add(5);
        final Set<Integer> s3 = new HashSet<>();
        s3.add(1);
        s3.add(4);
        s3.add(3);
        s3.add(2);
        final Set sets[] = {s1, s2, s3};
        final Map<Set, Integer> costs = new HashMap<>();
        costs.put(s1, 5);
        costs.put(s2, 10);
        costs.put(s3, 30);
        System.out.println(minCostCollection(unv, sets, costs, new ArrayList<Set>(), sets.length - 1));
    }
```